# カルーセルで左右に矢印を出したい

Tags: onsen-ui

OnsenUIでWebアプリを開発しています。

その中でカルーセル(ons-carouselコンポーネント)を使用する画面があり、左右に続くコンテンツがあるかどうかをユーザに示す矢印("<"と">")を表示したいと考えています。

矢印の表示はOnsenUIの標準機能で可能でしょうか？
それとも、自力で実装するしかないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onsen UIの`onsen-css-components-blue-basic-theme.css`の2731行に`ons-list-item`の`＞`を表示するクラス`.list__item--chevron:before`がありますので、これをコピーし左用(`＜`)、右用(`＞`)のクラスを作成すれば実現できます。

CSS

```
.carousel-item-chevron-l:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 16px;
    top: 50%;
    color: #ddd;
    line-height: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    content: "\f104";
}
.carousel-item-chevron-r:before {
    position: absolute;
    right: 16px;
    top: 50%;
    color: #ddd;
    line-height: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    content: "\f105";
}
```

HTML

```
<ons-carousel-item>
    <div class="carousel-item-chevron-l"></div>
    <div class="carousel-item-chevron-r"></div>
</ons-carousel-item>
```

Comment: 実際に試して表示されることを確認しました。
やはり自前で表示するしかないのですね。

ありがとうございます。